# Warning message when caps lock is on while entering password is not working and also initial scale is not recognized in google chrome only

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

I am using a JavaScript function to check if caps lock is on and on the console window I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at login.js:41"

In google chrome's console window I also get an error 
"The key "intial-scale" is not recognized and ignored"

I tried searching for the causes of this problem and I saw people saying that this may be because the function is executed before the DOM runs so I tried adding window.onload before the function but it didn't fix the issue.

```js
// array of objects to store adminstrators data 
var usersObj =[
    {
        username: "karim",
        password: "karim2019"
    },

    {    
        username: "nourhan",
        password: "noura2019"
    },

    {
        username: "nariman",
       password: "nariman2019"
    }
]

// function to authenticate login information and proceed to the next page 
function getLoginInfo()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++)
    {
        if(username == usersObj[i].username && password == usersObj[i].password)
        {
            alert("Login successful..");
            document.getElementById("loginf").action = "dashboard.html";
            return
        }
    }
    alert("Username or password is incorrect!");
    document.getElementById("loginf").action = "login.htm";
}

var input = document.getElementById("password");

var text = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keyup", window.onload=function(event)
{
    if (event.getModifierState("CapsLock"))
    {
        text.style.visibility = "visible";
    } 
      else
    {
        text.style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
});
```

```css
.row {
    margin-top: 5%;
}
/* Bordered form */
form {
    margin-top: 20%;
  }

  /* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1% 2%;
    margin: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 p{
   display: none;
 }
  /* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 1% 2%;
    margin: 1%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* Add a hover effect for buttons */
button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  /* Add padding to containers */
.container {
    padding: 1.5%;
  }

  /* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 1.5%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loginstyles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            
            <div class="col">
                <form  id = "loginf" name="loginf" method="POST">
                    <div>
                        <h1>Account Login</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div><hr></div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                    

                        <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                        <p id="text">WARNING!Caps Lock is ON.</p>
                        
                        

                        
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember">Remember me
                        </label>
                        <span class="psw"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></span>
                        <button onclick="getLoginInfo()" type="submit">Login</button>
                    </div>
                    
                   
                        
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by wrapping the eventlistener inside a function that runs when the window loads

```js
// array of objects to store adminstrators data 
var usersObj =[
    {
        username: "karim",
        password: "karim2019"
    },

    {    
        username: "nourhan",
        password: "noura2019"
    },

    {
        username: "nariman",
       password: "nariman2019"
    }
]

// function to authenticate login information and proceed to the next page 
function getLoginInfo()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for(i = 0; i < usersObj.length; i++)
    {
        if(username == usersObj[i].username && password == usersObj[i].password)
        {
            alert("Login successful..");
            document.getElementById("loginf").action = "dashboard.html";
            return
        }
    }
    alert("Username or password is incorrect!");
    document.getElementById("loginf").action = "login.htm";
}


window.onload=function()
{
    var input = this.document.getElementById("password");
    var text = this.document.getElementById("text");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event)
    {
        if(event.getModifierState("CapsLock"))
        {
            text.style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            text.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
};
```